# Parse Error on PostgreSQL when using ST_AsText

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps, pgadmin-4

I am new to using POSTGIS and PostgreSQL.

I am trying to convert PostGIS coordinates into lat and long values. When I copy one of the values and query like

```
SELECT ST_AsText('0101000000A7E8482EFFC55B402063EE5A42064140');
```

The query runs without an error. But when I try the query for the entire table column like

```
SELECT ST_AsText(GPS) from schema.table;
```

I am getting an error saying

```
" 0101000000A7E8482EFFC" <-- parse error at position 22 within geometry
```

The column data type is text. I am unsure why the ST_AsText is unable to read the whole text and stops at position 21.

Additional information:
PostgreSQL version : 10.7
pgAdmin : 4.5
PostGIS: 2.4.3

I am using Python SQLAlchemy to Insert the tables directly into PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you're trying to convert existing postgis geometry into lat and lon, could you try using the ST_X(GEOM), and ST_Y(geom) functions to see if those work instead? And, is the geometry valid on the point that is throwing the error?

Comment: Also I see you've tagged pgadmin4 - try using DBeaver - the new geometry viewer is super useful, as well as dbeaver generally being a much better interface for an analyst vs. a database administrator...

Comment: is the GPS column storing PostGIS' `GEOMETRY` bytea representation as `TEXT`?? That column really should be the appropriate `GEOMETRY` type. I guess the actual string literal of bytea can be cast implicitly when passed to `ST_AsText`, but not when passed as column reference...

Comment: @ThingumaBob running `\df++ st_asText` show an (undocumented) version that gets a text input, cast it to geometry and call the common `st_asText(geometry)`` function. This cast should be valid on txt/bytea

Comment: @JGH aha! nice find, so you are absolutely right, it's the whitespaces rather than casting limtations. never thought someone would find this signature to be worth adding ,)

Comment: @ThingumaBob I am not in charge of the data and I am just uploading the data given. Thanks for your response though. I will pass it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message mentions `" 0101000000A7E8482EFFC"`, with a trailing space, which makes the geometry invalid.

The dirty solution is to `trim` your data

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(TRIM(GPS)) from schema.table;
```

```sql
with src as (select ' 0101000000A7E8482EFFC55B402063EE5A42064140'::text txt)
select st_asText(txt::geometry) from src;

ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  " 0101000000A" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry

with src as (select ' 0101000000A7E8482EFFC55B402063EE5A42064140'::text txt)
select st_asText(trim(txt)) from src;

        st_astext
-------------------------
 POINT(111.0937 34.0489)
(1 row)
```

The clean solution, as suggested in the comments by @ThingumBob, is to have a real geometry column and to sanitize what you put in it.

Comment: It works well. Thanks.